# 'package:flutter/src/widegets/text.dart':failed assertion:line 235 pos 15 : 'data ! = NULL ' : is not true

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

question：'package:flutter/src/widegets/text.dart':failed assertion:line 235 pos 15 : 'data ! = NULL ' : is not true
code：

```
body: Container(
     child: FutureBuilder(
       future: _getQu(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
         if (snapshot.data == null){
           return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(" تحميل البينات........"),
          ),
           );
         }Dn.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title: Text(snapshot.data[index].questions ?? ""),
```

The data of Text Widget must not be null.So you can modify it to look like the above. If `snapshot.data[index].questions == null`, it will accept the empty string.

Comment: Welcome this is four first answer. May I suggest you edit the answer and elaborate a bit more by explaining why you think this is the solution.

Comment: @JackShen  This is not the number
I do not know why this line appears

Comment: Sorry, the line number is in 'flutter/src/widegets/text.dart'. Can you post complete code? @SarahAlramly

Comment: @JackShen
class _MyhomePageState extends State<MyhomePage> {
    Future <List<Qu>> _getQu() async{
   var data= await http.get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfwZmvEBbc?indent=2");
   var jsonData =json.decode(data.body);
   List<Qu> qu =[];
   for(var u in jsonData){
     Qu qur = Qu(u["questions"],u["ansar"]);
     qu.add(qur);
   }
   print(qu.length);
   return qu;